# How to connect to wireless in Windows7?

Tags: windows-7, wireless-networking

I haven't used Windows for several years.  I was just trying out a Windows 7 machine and couldn't get online with my wireless. Everytime I connect to the wireless signal in the house, it establishes the connection but shows a "limited access connection" annotation.  And I couldn't really access Web sites in a browser.  How to fix this?

Comment: does your router have DHCP enabled and a free IP address for the wireless? is there any whitelisting needed for the MAC address?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Generally you get that when the PC doesn't receive an IP address from the router.  Did you have to specify the wireless password?  Are you certain you used the correct one?

Comment: Yes, I connected the same wireless signal and used the same password as what I use on a Macbook.

Comment: And if I also plug in the ethernet cable, I can access http://192.168.1.254 in browser, it shows an information page about the router and connection.  I can't access the page when only on wireless.

Comment: Make sure you haven't manually defined a DNS server in the TCP/IP settings

Comment: Where do I confirm this?

Comment: **Control Panel\Network and Internet\Network Connections** right click the wireless device click **Properties** then click **Internet Protocol Version 4** then **Properties** make sure they both have **Obtain an IP address automatically** checked.

Answer (score 0):

If **Obtain an IP address automatically** is checked. Then try typing `ipconfig /release` then `ipconfig /renew` into cmd. Or try right-clicking the network icon on the right side of the taskbar and click **Troubleshoot problems**.